# Dropped connection with HAProxy in TCP mode + "transparent client IP"

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, pfsense

**Basic Setup**

We are running HAProxy in a pair of PFsense boxes. In front, we're serving a bunch of IP adresses, and for each IP address, we have a pair of SSL offloaders behind this.

The HAProxy is used to loadbalance between the two. The config is roughly this:

```
frontend FOO_FRONT_80
    bind            5.5.5.5:80 name 5.5.5.5:80  transparent 
    mode            tcp
    log             global
    maxconn         10000
    timeout client  30000
    use_backend FOO_BACK_80



backend FOO_BACK_80
    mode            tcp
    log             global
    option          log-health-checks
    balance         source
    timeout connect 30000
    timeout server  30000
    retries         3
    source ipv4@ usesrc clientip
    server          FOO_LB_001 10.0.0.21:80 check inter 10000  weight 100 
    server          FOO_LB_002 10.0.0.22:80 check inter 10000  weight 100
```

This is serving a couple of tens of thousand of simultanous connections.

Here's a picture:

[image]

**Issues**

All regular GET requests to the loadbalancers go through OK. But POST requests (anything with a request body > 50kBytes) does not, with the connection apparently being cut between the HAProxy and the backend Apaches.

In a lab environment, we have been unable to reproduce this. But in production, these issues disappeared when we switched OFF the transparent client IP setting.

We're now trying to figure out what might be causing this. Could it be a big (I doubt that) or is it some misconfiguration somewhere (where?).

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

ruben

Comment: which version of haproxy do you use? if it's not the latest are you able to update to the latest version?

Comment: @Aleksandar it's 1.7.11 - afaik the most current version available packaged for pfsense.

Comment: I would suggest to use the **proxy protocol** instead of *transparent*. there is a module for apache for this.

Comment: @Aleksandar i didnt know that there was an apache mod. have you used it in high-load scenarios? is it stable?

Comment: I don't use apache any more. Just searched for proxy protocol and apache